# Do I still have to manually include matchmedia.js and respond.js with modernizr?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, modernizr, respond.js

The question is basically in the title: will the [modernizr build tool](http://modernizr.com/download/) include respond.js and/or matchmedia.js when I select media queries to be included (under extra)?

Or do I have to include it manually with Modernizr.load? (I've looked at the source, but I can't really tell whether respond.js is in there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the "Media Queries" option under "Extra" in the build tool, your Modernizr build will include a matchmedia.js-like function called `Modernizr.mq()` (see the [documentation](http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq)). The code's basically the same as matchmedia as both were written by [Paul Irish](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-boVm8ZJ5ZjY/TxR3WhSb8hI/AAAAAAAAB5s/rJSnIhwcsOU/s250-c-k-no/IMG_1363.JPG).

Respond.js isn't included in Modernizr, but [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) can create an [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) build which includes Modernizr and Respond.js.

Comment: It appears that Modernizr.mq() is equivalent to window.matchMedia().matches(). In that sense, yes it supports matchMedia(). However, it does not seem to support window.matchMedia().addListner(). In other words, if I wanted to add listeners for my media queries, I could not do it.

Comment: Correct – it isn’t a complete polyfill.